# Jekyll -d adding space in front of directory name

Tags: jekyll

I'm trying to change the destination of a jekyll build to `_site-dist` rather than `_site`. I did this by running `jekyll build -d _site-dist`.

The result is that the files are written to " _site-dist" instead of "_site-dist". It's adding a space to the beginning of the directory name.

How do I resolve this?

---

- *Ubuntu 14.04*
- *Jekyll 2.5.3*
- *Ruby 2.2.0*

Comment: I don't know if this will work, but have you tried passing `-d_site-dist` (without the space).

Comment: Well, that worked. Very weird. I'm pretty sure that's not how the tag should work. I'll have to report this.

Comment: not reproduced with  ruby 1.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug. The workaround is to squish the tag and the directory together like this: `jekyll build -d_site-dist`

*Note: The cause of this bug was never found. The issue stopped occurring a few days later without any action on my part. It's a mystery.*